# Syncing Layers to each other

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online

I have a master editing map that I make most of my edits in and then I have a WebMap separate of this. I make many of my edits to the WebMap in ArcGIS Pro. The WebMap and my master editing map share the same layers, however, these layers in the WebMap are hosted feature layers, while the ones in my master editing map or not. Is there a way for me to sync these layers together to where when I make edits to the layer in my master editing map, the hosted feature layer also changes?

Comment: you would need branch versioning https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/versioning-types.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_6FA2CFB5F9484FF096740D653C674B5D (you would be user-version A or B) note: Branch versioned datasets are not accessible in ArcMap and versions earlier than ArcGIS Pro 2.1.

Comment: If there is any chance the same feature could be edited in both places, you will also have to have some strategy for deciding which change 'wins'.  This is usually a manual process.